# Createjs to PIXIJS conversion

Tags: javascript, createjs, pixi.js

used CREATEJS to develop a casino slot game and it started to behave slow on many devices. Because of this, I want to stop using createJS, but switch to pixiJS without deleting all the code and if someone did a similar conversion or what would be a list of best practices to use when doing this conversion or if there are any tools online that can do such conversion or if there is a migration tool for pixiJS, please let me know about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and if possible add some minimal, complete, verifiable example. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you are sticking with mostly Bitmaps (no Vectors or text, which won't work in Pixi anyways), consider updating to 1.0, and using EaselJS StageGL. Its pretty much a drop-in replacement for Stage using WebGL, and is comparable to Pixi in terms of speed. https://blog.createjs.com/stagegl-faster-better-stronger-webgl-update-easeljs/

Comment: Thanks Lanny, its a lot of improvement. It really works with new version. But for the mask, i used alphamaskfilter and i want the mask to be static and not to move the masked object. here is my fiddle. Can u let me know where iam wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/L9xy84yu/24/